# symfony2 entity validation regexp a-z A-Z 0-9

Tags: php, regex, validation, symfony

Is there a built-in way in symfony2 to validate a string (in my case the username and one other property) against the classic a-z, A-Z and 0-9 rule?

Would I have to write that in regexp myself as a custom validator? (if so, hint where to look is appreciated)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the native [Regex validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html),

It's as simple as using the Regex assert annotation as follow,

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class YourClass
{
   /**
    * @Assert\Regex("/[a-zA-Z0-9]/")
    */        
    protected $yourProperty;
}
```

You can also customize your validation by setting the `match` option to `false` in order to assert that a given string does not match.

```
/**
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *     pattern="/[a-zA-Z0-9]/",
 *     match=false,
 *     message="Your property should match ..."
 * )
 */
protected $yourProperty;
```

Using annotation is not the only way to do that, you can also use [YML, XML and PHP](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html#basic-usage), check the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html), it's full of [well explained examples](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html#basic-usage) that address this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get the previous answer to work correctly. I think it is missing a repeat quantifier (`+`). Even then, it would match substrings if the offending characters were at the beginning or end of the string, so we need start `^` and end `$` restrictions. I also needed to allow dashes and underscores as well as letters and numbers, so my final pattern looks like this.

```
 * @Assert\Regex("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+$/")
```

I am using Symfony 2.8, so I don't know if the Regex validation changed, but it seems unlikely.

A good resource for testing regex patterns is [regex101.com](https://regex101.com).

Comment: The restrictions are a good idea. The reason the previous example didn't work is 'match=false' results in the validation passing only if the regex does *NOT* match.