# Symfony Validation with Data-Transformers

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I have a form for a Product entity and I'm putting tags inside it.

I followed the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) and used a data-transformer : the user enter a space-separated string which is exploded into a Tag collection.

I now want to validate the string that  is transformed into the collection so it cannot use meta-characters.

I tried this, but it doesn't work : (cf. [symfony2 entity validation regexp a-z A-Z 0-9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701797/symfony2-entity-validation-regexp-a-z-a-z-0-9))

```
//AppBundle\Entity\Product.php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *      pattern="/[\w\s]+/",
 *      match=true,
 *      message="Your property should match my damn regex !"
 * )
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *      name="contenus_tags",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="contenu_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $tags;
```

How can I make this ?

Comment: Add a validation in the tag class on its name, and a "valid" assertion on tags in your product class?

Comment: Whoa, never thought it would work even after data transformation o_O Symfony is too damn clever ! Thank you !
You can add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a validation in the tag class on its name, and a "valid" assertion on tags in your product class:

```
//AppBundle\Entity\Tag.php
/**
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *      pattern="/^[a-Z0-9]+$/",
 *      match=true,
 *      message="Your property should match my damn regex !"
 * )
 */
private $name;
```

```
//AppBundle\Entity\Product.php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @Assert\Valid()
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *      pattern="/[\w\s]+/",
 *      match=true,
 *      message="Your property should match my damn regex !"
 * )
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *      name="contenus_tags",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="contenu_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $tags;
```